# BER based transmitter gain

Tags: matlab, hilbert-transform

Are there any direct relation formula between BER and Transmitter gain. The higher the transmitter gain is, the better the BER performance is. In here, I want to plot graph for the BER based on different transmitter gains and compare the MATLAB simulation vs experimental results.

Comment: BER curves are usually done over a $\frac{E_b}{N_0}$ x-axis. Which makes a lot of sense -what distorts the reception is how bad the noise is in relation to the receive power. Now, if you have a simple channel model, you can convert transmit power into receive power. Then you add a noise model (e.g. awgn with constant power spectral density), and relate that to how many bits you've transmitted, and then you get one of the many many many BER curves that you can find in literature. The way such curves look depend on a lot of factors, including your modulation, channel coding, implementation,

Comment: ... Diversity order

Answer (score -1):

To simplify, let's consider the transmission of a single pulse $$s(t) = A p(t),$$ where $p(t)$ has energy 1, and the transmitted energy is $A^2$.

Note that the value of $A$ is related to the transmitted energy. If the transmitter's amplifiers have a lot of gain, then $A$ will be large. The AWGN channel model does not make explicit mention of this, but you should always keep it in the back of your mind that it's only a model, in a real system there is a lot more going on.

Now, the receiver has a filter matched to $p(t)$; when sampled at the right time, the matched filter output is equal to $A$. The receiver's noise has PSD equal to $N_0/2$, which is constant and independent of $A$.

You can then easily conclude that increasing the transmitted power will increase the SNR at the matched filter's output, which will in turn decrease the probability of error.

So, one possible approach would be:

- Define a fixed transmitted constellation. Let's say you use BPSK with constellation $\lbrace -1, 1 \rbrace$.
- Define a transmitter gain G.
- Calculate the SNR at the filter's output: $2G^2/N_0$.
- Plot the BER as a function of this SNR.